# UITextField doesn't update

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have created programmatically 2 UITextfield that I want cleared before editing. The problem is when I clic on the UITextfield, they clear well (I check it with NSLog) but the View doesn't update.

When I edit with the keyboard the textfield, the new string seems to append the existent string (instead of clearing and editing) but, in fact the textfield doesn't edit.

I have read all the forums relative to this problem but I can't find a solution. It seems to be a thread problem with the UITextFieldDelegate...

Note that the UITextFields are embedded in a scrollView.

I have already tried setNeedsDisplay on my textfields, clearsOnEditing property, putting the code in the "textFieldsShouldBeginEditing" and "textFieldsDidBeginEditing" methods and  a lot of other things without success. Some help would be very cool !

The code relative to the textfields :

```
@implementation gaineViewController


- (UITextField *)hauteurText {
if(!_hauteurText){
_hauteurText = [[UITextField alloc]init];
_hauteurText.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
_hauteurText.delegate = self;
_hauteurText.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;

}
return _hauteurText;
}


- (UITextField *)largeurText {
if(!_largeurText){
_largeurText = [[UITextField alloc]init];
_largeurText.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
_largeurText.delegate = self;
_largeurText.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
}

return _largeurText;
}



- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

if ([textField isEqual:self.largeurText]) {
NSLog(@"%@",self.largeurText.text);
self.largeurText.text=@"";
NSLog(@"%@",self.largeurText.text);
}

if ([textField isEqual:self.hauteurText]) {
NSLog(@"%@",self.hauteurText.text);
self.hauteurText.text=@"";
NSLog(@"%@",self.hauteurText.text);
}


return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you tried checking textField == self.hauteurText. This is valid because you're actually looking at the same exact instance (identity matters instead of equality).

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you posted. Post more.

Comment: Where/how do you actually put the text fields into a view?

Answer (score 0):

You said "It seems to be a thread problem with the UITextFieldDelegate..."

What do you mean, thread problem? UIView objects in iOS are not thread-safe. Are you trying to update the UI from a background thread? If so, that's your problem.